# sixty eight thousand 68000 tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The title exagerates slightly but I've noticed there are three tags dealing with the Motorola 68xxx series

- [motorola-68000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-68000) - four followers, seven questions
- [mc68000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc68000) - two followers, one question
- [m68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m68k) - four followers, two questions

Should these tags be merged or aliased or something?

Comment: I've retagged the mc68000 question and strengthened the tag wikis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good catch.

To compare with other practice, [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) is a main tag and [intel-8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-8080) is a synonym that points to it.

So, I would suggest we should use [68000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/68000), and point [motorola-68000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-68000) to it.

We could then either also synonimize [mc68000](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc68000) and [m68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m68k) or retag the questions and let these two tags die out.  I would prefer the latter option.

Comment: I've seen mc68000 used rarely, but it might be more common regionally.  m68k I usually see used to generically refer to the entire line of processors 68000, 68020, etc in the same way you'd use x86 instead of specifically 286, 386, etc so it might be a valid tag depending on the scope of the question.

Comment: @mnem:  Granted.  Although I've usually seen the series referred to as 680x0 or 68xxx.  But then synonyms could help there too.

Comment: I think we need a tag for the general line of processors. There should probably also be a tag for popular models that synonymn the main tag. For example, if our main tag was 68000 and somebody wanted to ask a question about the 68020 and they did a tag search for 68020, the main tag does show up until you press the 2 key but then it disappears.

Comment: What is the etiquette on accepting answers on discussion questions? Should I leave the question with no accepted answers until we have resolved something? Or should I accept one now for the sake of form?

Comment: @JeremyP: The guideline is that you accept the answer that you feel helps you personally the most.  Although, you don't have to accept any answer.  Don't feel pressured to accept.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I would have made [tag:intel-8080] and [tag:motorola-68000] the "main" tags for clarity. The only disadvantage of a longer tag name is when you have to type it in, but the synonyms solve that.

Comment: Especially for early CPUs second sourcing, in case with th 8080 with more than 20 licencees, was quite common, and not a few did differ from the original product. So adding a manufacturer name as part of a tag can be a burden. I would rather prefer tags like 8080 or 68000, than including the manufacurer name. and as @mnem already pointed out, for CPU families, a generic family tag that not only includes various manufactureres, but also verious (mostly) compatible models is a worthwhile addition.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is that a good catch, but it's good practice. With under 1K questions currently, developing the habit of finding, and resolving, tag related situations now, will make maintenance so much easier as the site grows, as we all hope it does. As an example, see [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8290/686699) cleanup request from Super User. Currently that tag has 690 questions to edit/retag. At one point it was over 1000 questions. It continues to dwindle, slowly. And even with the notice in the tag wiki, it was used 2 days ago! Bite the bugs early, and there's a lot less work for the exterminators later.

Comment: Yes it is good practice, and we have already tidied up a few tags in the last year.  It is also good to keep the principle of monitoring tags in the community's consciousness.